# Using dictionary in Visual Basic: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, dictionary, text-files, streamreader

Whilst creating this program in visual studio 2010 i have encountered a problem.

I read in contents of a textfile and search through each line to make sure when adding a new product, that their are no existing IDs the same. contents of file look like this:

```
0001|Unsmoked Middle Bacon
0002|Smoked Middle bacon
0003|Unsmoked Bits
```

So if a user tries to add a value '0001' it springs an error. Only my code is springing an error...

```
appPath = Application.StartupPath
    productDB = New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
    For Each line In IO.File.ReadAllLines(appPath & "/productlist.txt")
        Dim data = line.Split("|")
        productDB.Add(CInt(data(0)), data(1))
    Next


 If productDB.ContainsKey(newID) Then
        MsgBox("Prompt of same ID")
    Else
        MsgBox("Accepted fine")
    End If
```

on the line - *productDB.Add(CInt(data(0)), data(1))* - I seem to be springing the error

```
ArgumentException was unhandled.

An item with the same key has already been added.
```

Alot of people have been mentioning their resources.resx file messing things up, but i have tried all sorts and nothing seems to be helping :(

cheers,
robbie.

Comment: Where is newId assigned?

Comment: Somewhere in your file you have the same ID more than once. Remember that `0001` is the _same_ integer as `00001`, `01`, or just `1`, and all of those will result in the same key.

Comment: So should I use it as a string?

Comment: I have 'newID = txtIdAdd.Text' above all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own silly mistake.

There was already a duplicate entry within the textfile. (I had about 40 lines)

So it wasn't anything to do with the 4 digits I was wanting to enter, the error was happening upon reading in each line.

```
"D'oh" - Homer Simpson
```